# Using convergence to prove an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, convergence-divergence

Say I have:
$$B^Tx = 0$$
$$x \geq 0$$
$$r^{(n)} \geq 0$$

If $Bx - r$ converges to a vector how do i show the dot product of this vector with x is positive?

**Solution:** This can be done by simply using algebraic operations on the limit and showing that it is non-negative.